# no non-missing arguments to max

Tags: r, word-cloud

I am trying to create a word cloud with the image text below

```
wordcloud(words = wcdata_table$Dispensed_State, freq = wcdata_table$Date,scale=c( ,0.25),
      max.words=10, colors=brewer.pal(5, "Accent"))
```

and I keep getting the error:

```
> Error in -freq : invalid argument to unary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

[image]

picture of script

I have all the other script but for some reason, I keep getting this error message. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
 #INSTALLING PACKAGES
 install.packages("data.table") #fread
 install.packages("dplyr") #ranking frequency
 install.packages("grDevices") #png function
 install.packages("wordcloud") #wordcloud
 install.packages("RColorBrewer") #brewer colors

 #libraries
 library(data.table)
 library(dplyr)
 library(grDevices)
 library(wordcloud)
 library(RColorBrewer)

 #read in data table
 #already have data on computer called myData and don't want to 
 overwrite
 wcdata = fread("7-2_assessment.csv")

 #convert to data table
 wcdata = as.data.table(wcdata)

 #table of despensed state column
 #filter by value
 wcdata_tab = wcdata[DispensedState!=""]
 wcdata_tab2 = wcdata_tab[,.N, by=Date]

 #50 states
 wcdata_table = wcdata_tab2[order(-N)] %>% head(50) %>% 
 rename("DispensedState" =N, "States"= "DispensedState")

 #wordcloud
 png("Dispensed State.png", width =14,height=10, units= 'in', 
 res=400)
 par(mar = rep(0, 4))
 set.seed(1337)
 wordcloud(words = wcdata_table$DispensedState, freq = 
 wcdata_table$Date,scale=c( ,0.25),
          max.words=10, colors=brewer.pal(5, "Accent"))
```

Comment: Hint: This is an r question, not rstudio. Tagging it as rstudio is nonhelpful. As well, scale=c( ,0.25) in malformed . It must be length 2, not an error. I have not examined further, however.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of data and code. We're not going to type this out to reproduce. Rather, copy and paste the code, and use `dput()` to generate code to copy and paste here in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: HI Phil, thanks for letting me know that.

Comment: Why are you passing Date to the freq argument?

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to use just dispersed states, I was thinking I should have used number of records column instead.

Comment: Its always better to provide the community with some code example rather than screenshots of your data.